# xamarin.forms - uniquely identify controls in listview in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin.forms

I have a listview that is filled from backend c# code.

I have one label and one image defined in it. And I have given x:Name property in XAML.

Now, my question is I want to access those two labels in backend c# code. But both the labels are not accessible because they are in listview. If I put label outside listview, I can access it in the code.

**Please avoid syntax errors.** My code works fine. I want to access these elements so that I can change style for phone and tablet.

My XAML code :

```
// ...
<ListView x:Name="DentistList">
   <Listview.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ViewCell>
           <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" x:Name="DoctorImage"/>
           <Label Text="{Binding Name}" x:Name="DoctorName" />
         </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
   </Listview.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My c# code :

```
 ......
 DentistList.ItemSource = new List<Doctor>
 {
        // List of items defined here like...
        Name = "ABC",
        ImagePath = "img1.jpg"

        // Etc...
 };
```

Now, Below this list, I want to change style(like, fontsize etc...) of label and image. But I can not access them.

I tried to access them with FindByName() method but could not do that.

So, can anyone please answer ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't reference controls within a template by name because there are multiple instances of each control, one per item in the list.  If you want do customize them for tablet, try using OnIdiom in your XAML, or perhaps do it by using styles.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Jason but how can I change fontsize and textcolor using onidiom because I could not find solution to implrment it.

Answer (score 1):

From Jason's comment, you can change the `Label.FontSize` and `Label.TextColor` using `OnIdiom` like so:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" x:Name="DoctorName">
    <Label.TextColor>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Color"
                 Phone="Yellow"
                 Tablet="Blue"/>
    </Label.TextColor>

    <Label.FontSize>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="NamedSize"
                 Phone="Small"
                 Tablet="Large"/>
    </Label.FontSize>
</Label>
```

*Edit: Example using regular integer:

```
<Label.FontSize>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
             Phone="20"
             Tablet="30"/>
</Label.FontSize>
```

*Edit #2:
If you plan to use your `Label.FontSize` and `Label.TextColor` on multiple pages I would suggest adding the values into your `App.xaml` and then referencing them from your `ContentPage`s (you could also just add the value to the `ContentPage`'s `ResourceDictionary` if you are using the values multiple times but only on a single page):

App.xaml:

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.App">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

      <Color x:Key="MyTextColor">
        <Color.Accent>
          <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Color"
                   Phone="Yellow"
                   Tablet="Blue"/>
        </Color.Accent>
      </Color>

      <x:Double x:Key="MyFontSize">
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                 Phone="20"
                 Tablet="30"/>
      </x:Double>

    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Now in your `ContentPage`s:

```
<Label x:Name="DoctorName"
       Text="{Binding Name}"
       TextColor="{StaticResource MyTextColor}"
       FontSize="{StaticResource MyFontSize}"/>
```

If you want to use `NamedSize` instead you might need to use converter that I have seen on the Xamarin Forums. Let me know if you cannot find it and I can try to look around.

Comment: Thans for the comment @hvaughan3. I will try it..:) seems useful :)

Comment: Can I use static value instead of using small and large ?

Comment: @sweets If you are referring to regular integer values, of course you can. See edit.